# Changing <td> value with js function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im creating `<td>` with *jquery function*.
And I want to change its value by using js function.

**jquery is getting value and putting into table:**

```
tr.append("<td id='stsChange'>" + resul[i].status + "</td>");
```

I want to change `"<td id='stsChange'>"` value if its 1 Pending, else if 2 Success.

Please help me to solve this problem, Thanks!

I have done till here, but its not working.

```
        function insertText () {

   var status = document.getElementById('stsChange').innerText;
   alert(status);
   if(status = "1"){
       document.getElementById('stsChange').innerHTML = "Pending";
   }
   else if(status = "2"){
       document.getElementById('stsChange').innerHTML = "Success";
   }

}
```

Comment: Nobody will understand you. Can you give an example?

Comment: I want to point out that you are using assignment operator for comparison. 'if(status = "1")' should be if(status == "1")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append is much easier with jquery (else you would need to use [appendChild](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) - ):

I have the following solution based on what you gave:
(Please run code snippet at bottom of answer to see the result:)

```js
var result = [{status:1},{status:2},{status:1},{status:2}];
for(var i = 0, length = result.length; i < length; i++)
{
    $('#table_Status').append("<tr><td id='td_stsChange_" + i + "'>" + result[i].status + "</td></tr>");
  insertText(i);
}

function insertText(_i)
{
   var elem = document.getElementById('td_stsChange_' + _i);
   var status = elem.innerText;
   //alert(status);
   if(status === "1")
   {
       elem.innerHTML = "Pending";
   }
   else if(status === "2")
   {
       elem.innerHTML = "Success";
   }
}
```

```css
#table_Status {
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Table:
<table id="table_Status">
  <th>Status</th>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solve with jQuery object

```
function insertText($tdObject) {
     var newTextVal = $tdObject.text() == '2' ? 'Success' : 'Pending';
     $tdObject.text(newTextVal); 
}
```